# Adding a file to Libreoffice-writer as OLE and converting the Writer to PDF

Tags: pdf, libreoffice, libreoffice-base, libreoffice-writer

I have created a `Libre-office` Writer and attached `Spreadsheet` as `OLE object` using `Insert-Object-OLE-object`.

Now I converted my `Writer` file to a `PDF` file for distribution to general recipients. But when I did this, the attached `Spreadsheet` is not longer available to open upon Click.

Is there any way to keep that attached file clickable, so that when user click on that Icon in the `PDF` file, the `Spreadsheet` will open directly?

Any pointer will be really appreciated.

Comment: Excuse me, but in which program "the Spreadsheet will open directly"? Neither AcrobatReader nor other PDF viewers will do this, they don't know what Spreadsheet is. The PDF format has been declared "immutable" for many years, for viewing and printing only. Then they added interactivity to it, but not as much as we would like. If you want mutable fields in the document, then use controls (for example, TextBox)

Comment: To your question - but in which program "the Spreadsheet will open directly" - It is the default program for Spreadsheet in `.xlsx` extension in the user's system. So if user has `Libre-office` installed then it will open the spreadsheet, or `MS-office` etc.

Comment: Excuse me, you are talking about the PDF format? Perhaps you mean [Add an attachment](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/links-attachments-pdfs.html#add_an_attachment)?

Comment: I have an attachment with my original Writer file. Then I saved it as PDF. In this PDF file, that attachment is not clickable to open, but I want it clickable in the PDF as well

Comment: Sorry again - you not "saved it as PDF" but you "**export** it to PDF". In this case, the format of your original file completely changes, only their images remain from your original text document and the embedded spreadsheet. In other words - no, what you have in mind is impossible to implement by means of LibreOffice. You will need to look for a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Yes, I was suspecting this. However, do you know if there is any solution of this, even if that is out of the scope for Libre-office?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223750/discussion-between-johnsun-and-bogaso).

Comment: Was there a solution for the problem?